# Avoiding numerical overflow in unavoidable exponent calculation

Tags: python, overflow, exponential

I am having difficulty doing a Nernst modification to convert a voltage to a concentration gradient.

I have attempted this:

```
def calc_voltage_offset(self,config):
        Voltage = 350 #Voltage in mV, needs to be in mV
        outoverin = (10 ** Voltage / -61.5 )
        print(outoverin ** -1 )
        quit()
```

But I am running into the overflow error. Unfortunately I need the number to be this large and cannot seem to figure out a way to get around this. Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module: `from decimal import Decimal; Voltage = 3 ** 350 / Decimal(-61.5)`

Comment: Your final result is `-6.258005837083217459122985482E-166`.  Are you sure you don't need some parentheses somewhere?  Or maybe  .35 volts instead of 350 mV?  Do you have a reference to the actual formula used?

Comment: Yes I am using the inverse of the Nernst equation to back-calculate out the concentrations on either side of the membrane

Comment: Yes, that's not my area, so what is the *formula*?

Comment: What are the units of -61.5?  I suspect it should be `10 ** (voltage / -61.5)` and depending on units .35V instad of 350mV.  I'm sure you *don't* want 10 raised to the 350th power.